# Python script running with Heroku, Flask and Github doesn't get updated

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, heroku

I've a Python's scraper that is running every day with Heroku, Flask and Github Action. My script scrapes a website and input its data on a Spreadsheet. I decided to add one more column to my scraper, so I would get the data into two formats. My script runs locally and shows the new column as well. But, unfortunately, despite the code was updated on GitHub, it still add the data without the new column on the Spreadsheet. Why isn't this new column appearing on the Spreadsheet? Again: the script runs perfectly on Colab

Comment: Did you redeploy to Heroku?

Comment: It usually redeploy automatically, doesn't it? How can I check this?

Comment: Only if you configured it to. How do you normally deploy to Heroku?

Comment: Automatically with deploy.yml

Comment: `deploy.yml` isn't a Heroku thing. What is the specific tool that you are using to deploy? And how is it configured? Do you see evidence that your application is being deployed? Are you getting errors? Please read [ask].