# Why is Heroku log giving an old error instead of considering new code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, heroku

These are my Heroku's logs. It says that there were a problem with the path to 'manchete_oglobo' object. 'manchete_oglobo' means 'o globo headline', considering this homepage as o globo: https://oglobo.globo.com/

```
2022-06-08T17:20:08.303086+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9867]: Starting process with command `python send_email.py`
2022-06-08T17:20:08.971064+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9867]: State changed from starting to up
2022-06-08T17:20:15.335273+00:00 app[scheduler.9867]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-06-08T17:20:15.335302+00:00 app[scheduler.9867]:   File "/app/send_email.py", line 15, in <module>
2022-06-08T17:20:15.335398+00:00 app[scheduler.9867]:     manchete_oglobo = link_oglobo()
2022-06-08T17:20:15.335400+00:00 app[scheduler.9867]:   File "/app/scraper_portal.py", line 50, in link_oglobo
2022-06-08T17:20:15.335471+00:00 app[scheduler.9867]:     manchete_oglobo = doc.xpath('//h1[@class="teaser__title headline__title"]//a/@href')[0]
2022-06-08T17:20:15.335490+00:00 app[scheduler.9867]: IndexError: list index out of range
2022-06-08T17:20:15.471090+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9867]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-08T17:20:15.530981+00:00 heroku[scheduler.9867]: State changed from up to complete
```

Despite this error, my current version has other path to 'manchete_oglobo' which is not considered by Heroku. Why is Heroku getting an old path instead of the current one?

```
import requests
import lxml.html

def link_oglobo():
  url = 'https://oglobo.globo.com/'
  page = requests.get(url)
  doc = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)
  manchete_oglobo = doc.xpath('//h1[@class="title"]/parent::a/@href')[0]
  return manchete_oglobo
```

Comment: If you're seeing error messages that correspond with old code, the most likely answer is that you are running old code. Did you find a solution to [your last question about deployments not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72534972/354577)? Are you entirely sure that the code you're showing above is the code you've deployed to Heroku?

Comment: How can I make sure that I'm running the current code? I should update alone, just like before

Comment: Well, again, you'll have to share more details about how you are deploying. As I said on your last question, `deploy.yml` isn't a Heroku thing. Whatever tool you are using to deploy, you should start by looking at whatever logs or checkmarks or smiley face emoji it may provide to see if it thinks the deploy was successful. If possible, you should also compare the deployed commit hash with the commit hash you are trying to run.

Comment: It looks like maybe you're using GitHub Actions? I haven't used that, but take a look at the job status and any detailed information you can see. If it's like most other CI tools you should be able to find some pretty detailed output.

Comment: Yes, with GitHub Actions too: https://github.com/gabrielacaesar/meu-jornal-newsletter

Comment: @Chris I'm very new in programming. That's why I can't find out my mistake. I don't understand why the script would stop working